# How can I specify my own comparer code for a DataGridView field?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have an app written using .net 4.8 WinForms with a `DataGridView`. It populates the grid with values and I can click on the grid's headers to make it sort by this field's value and again to reserve order.

This works great, except the order is all wrong. That's because it is using the default string comparer. For one of my fields, I want it to use a custom comparer function I've written.

How (if) can I configure it that one of my fields should be sorted by my custom comparer when the user clicks on the table headings?

Comment: The `DataGridView` has a [DataGridView.SortCompare Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare?view=net-5.0)

Comment: [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks): This event occurs only when the `DataSource` property is not set and the `VirtualMode` property value is false. Are you using data-binding (setting DataSource property?)

Comment: @JohnG - That works great, thank you. I think I was expecting an event like that to be part of a column instead of the DataGridView itself.

Comment: @JohnG - If you want the rep-points, you could make that an answer, perhaps including a note that it only works when you don't populate the table with DataSource referencing Reza Aghaei's comment.

Comment: Honestly, I did not read the Remarks section as @Reza Aghaei mentioned, which is an important note that I neglected to mention. I assumed this would work with a data bound grid and looking at it now… it makes sense that it won’t. Usually using a grid that is not data bound, creates more work for you and I jumped the gun in my assumption. Since you never stated if the grid was data bound or not, and I assumed it was, then my comment is not helpful. You can add an answer and note what I missed and I will give ya an up vote.

Comment: Lastly, I have to ask, what “special” type of sorting are you needing and is there some reason you don’t use a data source for the gird?

Comment: @JohnG - I was actually having a different problem with a field populated by ints but with some NULLs. Sorting the table was throwing an exception when it tried to convert NULL to int. I had searched for this specific error but the solutions offered didn't work for me. I knew what I really needed was a custom comparing function that applied my own rules on NULLs. I posted my question to avoid wasting time with answers that, for whatever reason, wouldn't work for my case.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried to put the data into a `DataTable`? In my tests, sorting an `int` type column worked as expected when some values were null or “empty.” I question your comment… _”I knew what I really needed was a custom comparing function that applied my own rules on NULLs”_ … this is not true for a simple `int` type… depending on how the data is stored. In other words, if you use a `DataTable` instead of directly adding the values to the grid, then, the sorting will work without exceptions. In addition, it will be a proper `int` sort instead of the `string` sort.

Comment: @JohnG - I didn't use a DataTable. The records come in a stream so I use AddRow and set cell values. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but a mixture of ints and nulls cause an error. (Were it not for my custom comparing function.)

Comment: And that is my point, DO use a `DataTable`. From my tests, the `int` column will sort properly without any additional code. Dont do things that "create" more work for you. Take the stream you use for AddRow and instead add the row to a `DataTable` then use the `DataTable` as a data source to the grid.